# Preview of google drive files without login

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

How we can get preview of google drive files in web without login into google account. In current scenario only public files are visible through embed link, we need to show preview of file in iframe which are not public and without login.

Comment: "not public" and "without login" are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

Here in lies the difference between the term "public" and "private".   The way google authentication works is that any data that is public is free for anyone to see.  If you set the file to public anyone can open it without being logged in or authenticated to Google.

Private files on the other hand you must have permission to access.  There is no way to preview a file you do not have permissions to access.  There is no workaround for this.

Comment: Thank you for response. I have access token for google drive api, So in that case how i can open file in iframe.

Comment: You cannot access or view private files which doesn't belong to you. The OAuth login's main purpose is to authenticate/authorize and protect the files of the owner. Sounds like you want to view someone's files that's why you're insisting on using your access token. How did you acquire that access token? You probably used your email. Hence, that access token can only be used to view your private files.

Answer (score 1):

I think "Publish" is what is you need. The file can still be "Private".

[Publish and embed Google Docs, Sheets, Slides & Forms](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/37579)
To make a document, spreadsheet, or presentation, available for a large audience to see, publish a file. After you publish your file, you’ll have a URL that you can send to anyone or embed into your website.

Comment: It then behave like public file. Anybody can see it. It will also indexed in search engine So no more private file.

Comment: That depends on where you place that iframe, if it is behind a login page it won't be public nor indexed, this is the best compromise.

Comment: User can see iframe src by inspect element and can copy it and then can open it anywhere.