# How to download PDF file from Google drive and view it

Tags: pdf, google-api, google-drive-api

I am requesting following google drive api for download file content 
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId?alt=media

I am getting following response header:

```
Status Code: 200 OK
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="37,36,35"
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 539096
Content-Type: application/pdf
Date: Thu, 23 Mar 2017 06:45:35 GMT
Expires: Thu, 23 Mar 2017 06:45:35 GMT
Server: UploadServer
Vary: Origin, X-Origin
Warning: 214 UploadServer gzipped
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
x-guploader-uploadid: AEnB2Ur3pm8DuMyKmFwS83qzuZZtsEG-WBzyq5pAEA-B3gzUFF7vJgpDr1FuHTH29dmH3qi-Cw8GRIBetNkp0cOi9SXZ2vs3yw
```

And in response body encoded pdf file something like this :

```
%PDF-1.7
%����

414 0 obj
<</Linearized 1/L 696774/O 417/E 31849/N 13/T 688378/H [ 716 821]>>
endobj

xref
414 21
0000000016 00000 n
0000001537 00000 n...
```

How can i view this response in readable pdf file.
Thanks.

Comment: What you are looking at is the raw data for a PDF file,  you should probably save it into a file.  Once its saved you will have to then open it in a pdf reader application.  How you do that is going to depend entirely on the language you are using try this https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I do not want to save it to any file, i want to render it in iframe directly.

Comment: you cant you must save the file an iframe can not handle a file stream.   http://stackoverflow.com/q/12974115/1841839

Comment: I am just stuck. I want to show google drive private files preview in iframe without user session, with the help of(access_token,client_id or api key). Is this possible?

Comment: yes if you download the file using the access token to your server and then show it in your Iframe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preview of google drive files without login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42810481/preview-of-google-drive-files-without-login)