# Google Drive API,preview file with iframe

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I need a preview of my google drive files,are my archives,but are private,but I dont want to login in My account to preview the file,how I can use the Oauth Authentication to preview the files?if yes how i can do it.I try to generate the webContentLink but needs a login too,Thanks

```
    $url_array = explode('?', 'My url permited');
    $url = $url_array[0];
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId('My client ID');
    $client->setClientSecret('My client secret');
    $client->setRedirectUri($url);
    $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setState('offline');
    $client->refreshToken('My refresh token with Oauth playground');
    $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
```

and After the connection with API I do the upload to google drive

```
        $content = file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);//pega o conteudo do arquivo
    $file = $service->files->create($fileMetadata, array(//função para inserir aonde tem 2 parametros,metadados e  conteudo/tipo e etc do arquivo
        'data' => $content,
        'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
        'uploadType' => 'multipart',
        'fields' => 'id,webViewLink,webContentLink,thumbnailLink'));
    printf("File ID: %s\n", $file->id);
```

I need this webViewLink to put in Iframe but without request login when I enter in the webViewLink

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth You should show what you have tried as a [mcve].

Comment: I dont think its a problem caused by my code,i just want to know how to do something, i already have the Oauth authentication establishe,I need to know what I have to do in the API.

Comment: But a [mcve] will give people context so they actually feel like helping you. Questions without code just don't get traction here. For example, the Drive API has various levels of access to items, and a few different ways of getting access to even the lowest level of access. We don't know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: ok I will update my question

Comment: the code is in the question

Comment: You cannot view private files without logging in. You need access. See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42810481/)

Answer (score 1):

Lets consider private user data.  Data that is owned by a user for example files you upload to your google drive account.   The only one who can see those files is the users who have access to them.   I cant just go over to your drive account and access your personal data.

Oauth2 gives us a way to grant applications (Clients) access to our personal data.  When you want to use an application you login to your google account, and are prompted with a consent screen to grant the application access to your data.  If the application (Client) requested offline access they will be given a refresh token which they can use at anytime to request an access token to access your data. In this way the application authenticates itself to google as you.  Without the refresh token your code would be prompting the user to request permission to access their data, with it the application doesn't need to prompt again as you have already granted it.

With the access token the application will be able to access the google drive api and your stored data.  This has nothing to do with the google drive web application.

**accessing private user data**

webViewLink will only work if the user in question who has the weblink has been granted access to the file or if the file is public.  They will be prompted to login if they are not already logged in so just make sure you have sure the files with the users.

Remember Oauth is used to grant your application access to a users data. You access that data though an api.  You cant programmaticly preview files using unless you create your own application for previewing files.  Your not going to be able to preview files in the  Google Drive Web Application.  Users will need to login to the application with their own accounts to see files on the google drive web application.

**Current logged in user**

Please run the following statement it will show you the user that you are currently logged in as.

```
$service->about->GetAbout(array('fields' => '*'));
```

You cant access google drive without being logged in you are logged in using your refresh token.

Comment: thanks but if I uploaded the files without login  with API,why I dont have granted access to preview  the file without login with  the same API?and do you know how I can do my own application for previewing files? I need this with urgency, thanks

Comment: You cant upload files without logging in.  The only way to upload to a users google drive account is to be logged in.     If you are using a service account then the service account is authenticated in your code so its logged in and uploading the files to its own account.  You cant preview files without being logged in as a user who has access to the file.   Creating an application to view files would be a big project  i wish you luck.

Comment: I upload the files without login,with my API configured,I generate a refresh token with Oatuh playground and setAccessType to offline and I upload files into my Drive without login in my account.That is the point,I do the upload with API without login,So why I cant preview with the same API?without login,Why I cant preview?I also download the file without login with my API...

Comment: Then you are logged in.  Offline access just gives you a refresh token you can use to request a new access token.   You are uploading files to YOUR drive account, there is no way to upload files to anyone's drive account without being logged in.   You cant preview it because your not logged in or the user who you are logging in with does not have access.

Comment: Please run the GetAbout method to see the user you are currently logged in as.

Comment: No,I am not logged in,I am in a navigator without login in some account of google drive,Yes I am uploading files to MY drive account and downloadiang too with the API,but i cant preview without a normal login, when you say 'Then you are logged in' is with the API alright?

Comment: You are using a refresh token. You are authenticated its the same thing.   You cant use a refresh token to access the preview you can only use the refresh token to access the api.   If who ever you give webViewLink  to does not personally have access to the file it links to then this user will not be able to see it.  Unless you set the file to public

Comment: So I can upload and download files to my google drive with the refresh token of my API and I can not preview the files with the same API who did the download and upload? is this?

Comment: The google drive api is a file store api,  you can create files, update files, and delete, list files.  It has no ability to preview anything.

Comment: whats is the sense,if I can download why I cant preview? whatever thanks, I will have to do something to preview my files.

Comment: do you know something to preview the files download them?

Comment: Depending upon the type of file for example PDF can be viewed in several applications.    You can't view it because that's not the APIs job.   it just lets you access the data creating applications to view it is something else